# how can i provide a confirmation form in the properties_list view before deleting the property

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

the code below deletes the property directly when the user clicks the delete btn, how can i edit the code to provide a confirmation form i.e modal where the user can choose to either delete or not.

**views.py**

```
def property_list(request):
  properties = Property.objects.all()

  context = {
    'properties': properties,
    'delete_template':'real_estate/property/delete.html',
  }
  return render(request, 'real_estate/property/list.html', context)

def delete_property(request, id):
  property = get_object_or_404(Property, id=id)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    property.delete()
    messages.success(request, f"you have successfully deleted {property.title}")
    return redirect('real_estate:property_list')

  context = {
    'property': property,
    'confirm_template':'real_estate/property/delete.html',
    'confirm_url': reverse('real_estate:delete_property', args=[property.id])
  }

  return render(request, context['confirm_template'], context)
```

**real_estate/property/list.html'**

```
{% extends "real_estate/base.html" %}
{% block title %} Property List {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  {% if properties %}
  <h1>properties list</h1>
  <a class="btn" href="{% url 'real_estate:add_property' %}" >add property</a>
  <ul>
    {% for property in properties %}
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'real_estate:property_details' property.id %}"> {{ property.title }} </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'real_estate:property_details' property.id %}">View</a>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'real_estate:edit_property' property.id %}">Edit</a>

        {% if request.GET.delete and request.GET.delete == property.id %}
          {% include confirm_template with property=property %}
        {% else %}
          <form action="{% url 'real_estate:delete_property' property.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
          </form>
        {% endif %}
        
      </li>
    {% endfor %}  
  </ul>
  {% else %}
    <h1>no properties added</h1>
    <a class="btn" href="{% url 'real_estate:add_property' %}" >add property</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial `display` value of the form div as `none`. Then add a seperate button outside the `<form>` tag to set its `display` value to `block`.

To close the modal, you can add another button inside the modal that sets the modal's `display` value back to `none` again.

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/whateverdat/07khzyt8/)

Be careful though. The button to close the model is inside the `form` element. In order to not to submit the form, you can set the button's `type` attribute to `button`. And you can set the confirmation button's `type` attribute to `submit`.

For turning your form div to a modal, you can refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) and play around the CSS a bit. Or for small projects that need quick styling, I can suggest you use [Pico.css](https://picocss.com/). It is easy to use and offers some prebuilt features, such as modals.

Comment: I have realized you display many items on the same page. In that case, the above method would not work. Alternatively, you could do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/whateverdat/3jmnctrd/). You can create the classes inside Django template with something like `class="modal-btn modal{{ your_instance.pk }}"` or `class="modal-btn modal{{ forloop.counter }}"`.